# Getting item id from newly created item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest, jquery, odata

I am using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise version. I am using below rest api code to add the record
I kept below code in common js file

```
function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, webUrl, newItem, success, failure) {
    var item = newItem;

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}

// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
```

Now I am using below code on my button click

```
var listName = "GatePass";
                        var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
                        var area = new Array();
                        $.each($("input[name='Building']:checked"), function () {
                            area.push($(this).val());
                        });
                        var newItem = {
                            "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
                            "Title": $("#txCompanyName").val(),
                            "Area": area.join(", "),
                            "FromDate": $("#fromDate").val()
                        };
                        CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, newItem, function () {
                            alert("New Item has been created successfully.");
                        }, function () {
                            alert("Ooops, an error occured. Please try again.");
                        });
```

Data's are adding successfully. I can see newly added data in my firebug console also. I know also that `success(data)` is the responsible for data. But I am not getting how to use that data in another function. Kindly somebody can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get ID of newly created item in success function which you can use later. 
Please refer below success function :

```
function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, webUrl, newItem) {
    var item = newItem;
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    });
}

CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, webUrl, newItem)
    .then(function(data){
        //success callback
        var NewlyCreatedItemId = data.d.ID;
    }, function(data){
        //failure callback
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I am getting ID in success function. Thanks rohit

Comment: So where should put this code in my js file or in calling function. If you can give full snippet

Comment: @Milind i have modified your 'CreateListItemWithDetails' and 'CreateListItemWithDetails' functions in my answer. You can get NewItemId in success callback as i have shown. Please try to implement this way, And let me know if its working for you.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow, if it works then I will mark it answer :) Thank you for your help

Comment: Isn't working for me in 2019 OnPrem. From data I get #document, which contains what looks like xml. How do I get to data.d.Id? Thanks